# Parse simple Html text

Tags: java, android, html-parsing

I have some simple html strings containing just **span** and **strong** tags and I want to display it in a TextView. Since TextView doesn't know about html classes I want to set myself the correct style depending on html attributes.

```
<span class="victoria line-text">Victoria line</span> to <strong>Highbury & Islington</strong>
```

Is it possible just with the help of [Html.fromHtml](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int)) method and Spanned object to get the below info or should I create my own parsing logic?

```
object1
{
   public String text="Victoria line";
   public String tag="Span";
   public String[] classes = {"victoria" "line-text" }
}

object2
{
   public String text=" to ";
   public String tag=null;
   public String[] classes =null;
}
object3
{
   public String text="Highbury & Islington";
   public String tag="Strong";
   public String[] classes =null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make this using only Html.fromHtml. Of course you can implement you own [handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.TagHandler?hl=en) for tags (it's for unrecognised tags, but you can change known tag name using regexp and handle them by yourself), or write you own tag parser, but tag classes it a different story.

I suggest to use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), it's html parsing lib, then select elements by class and replace class and tag with some custom tag. And feed result to Html.toHtml() with your custom tag handler.